# Authentication error when using AWS Glue (Spark connector) to migrate Azure Cosmos Db

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, azure-cosmosdb, aws-glue

I am following this AWS blog regarding migration from Azure Cosmos to AWS DynamoDb:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/migrate-from-azure-cosmos-db-to-amazon-dynamodb-using-aws-glue/

I am able to successfully create the AWS Glue Job as described in the article but keep running into the following error:

[image]

```
Py4JJavaError - An error occurred while calling o84.getSource. : java.lang.RuntimeException: Client initialization failed. Check if the endpoint is reachable and if your auth token is valid.
```

I have added the following connection options as described in the article:

```
spark.cosmos.accountEndpoint    https://<RESOURCE-NAME>.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:443/
spark.cosmos.database           <DATABASE-NAME>
spark.cosmos.container          users
```

**Already tried:**

1. I added another connection option spark.cosmos.accountKey and added the primary key from the Azure portal but no luck.
2. I have also tried to ping my endpoint and it is working fine.

Can someone help on how else to debug this?

Complete Stack Trace:

```
Py4JJavaError - An error occurred while calling o84.getSource. : java.lang.RuntimeException: Client initialization failed. Check if the endpoint is reachable and if your auth token is valid. More info: https://aka.ms/cosmosdb-tsg-service-unavailable-java at azure_cosmos_spark.com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxDocumentClientImpl.initializeGatewayConfigurationReader(RxDocumentClientImpl.java:535) at azure_cosmos_spark.com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxDocumentClientImpl.init(RxDocumentClientImpl.java:570) at azure_cosmos_spark.com.azure.cosmos.implementation.AsyncDocumentClient$Builder.build(AsyncDocumentClient.java:295) at azure_cosmos_spark.com.azure.cosmos.CosmosAsyncClient.<init>(CosmosAsyncClient.java:170) at azure_cosmos_spark.com.azure.cosmos.CosmosClientBuilder.buildAsyncClient(CosmosClientBuilder.java:1084) at azure_cosmos_spark.com.azure.cosmos.CosmosClientBuilder.buildAsyncClient(CosmosClientBuilder.java:1071) at com.azure.cosmos.spark.CosmosClientCache$.createCosmosAsyncClient(CosmosClientCache.scala:323) at com.azure.cosmos.spark.CosmosClientCache$.syncCreate(CosmosClientCache.scala:134) at com.azure.cosmos.spark.CosmosClientCache$.apply(CosmosClientCache.scala:76) at com.azure.cosmos.spark.ItemsReadOnlyTable.schema(ItemsReadOnlyTable.scala:111) at com.azure.cosmos.spark.CosmosItemsDataSource.inferSchema(CosmosItemsDataSource.scala:38) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceV2Utils$.getTableFromProvider(DataSourceV2Utils.scala:90) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceV2Utils$.loadV2Source(DataSourceV2Utils.scala:132) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$1(DataFrameReader.scala:209) at scala.Option.flatMap(Option.scala:271) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:207) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:171) at com.amazonaws.services.glue.marketplace.connector.CustomDataSourceFactory$.loadSparkDataSource(CustomDataSourceFactory.scala:114) at com.amazonaws.services.glue.marketplace.connector.CustomDataSourceFactory$.loadDataSource(CustomDataSourceFactory.scala:40) at com.amazonaws.services.glue.GlueContext.getCustomSource(GlueContext.scala:237) at com.amazonaws.services.glue.GlueContext.getCustomSourceWithConnection(GlueContext.scala:547) at com.amazonaws.services.glue.GlueContext.getSourceInternal(GlueContext.scala:1042) at com.amazonaws.services.glue.GlueContext.getSource(GlueContext.scala:848) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244) at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357) at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282) at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132) at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79) at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Comment: Your connection string shows that you're using the MongoDB API in Cosmos DB - `<RESOURCE-NAME>.mongo.cosmos.azure.com` - that's probably your issue. I'm guessing, given that you're using the Cosmos DB Spark connector, that this solution only works with the native Cosmos DB SQL API.